# In devtool command line tool is finish subcommand removed or replaced?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

The only relevant and easy to understand example I found to use `devtool` in a Yocto Workflow was the [Video from Tim Orling in Embedded Linux Conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiD7rB35CRE)

In his workflow:

1. He uses `devtool add` to add `nano`
2. `devtool build` to build it
3. `devtool deploy-target` to deploy it on `qemu`
4. `devtool undeploy-target` to remove `nano`
5. `devtool finish nano ../meta-foo`

**I tried doing the same thing but there is no subcommand `finish` in `devtool`**

when I try `devtool finish --help`

```
devtool finish --help
ERROR: argument <subcommand>: invalid choice: 'finish' (choose from 'create-workspace', 'add', 'modify', 'extract', 'sync', 'update-recipe', 'status', 'reset', 'build-image', 'deploy-target', 'undeploy-target', 'build', 'search', 'upgrade', 'edit-recipe', 'configure-help')
```

What is the equivalent subcommand for `devtool finish`. Is it `devtool reset`?

#### Build Host Environment

**Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS** virtual machine

**Bitbake version: 1.30.0**

`devtool` information

```
usage: devtool [--basepath BASEPATH] [--bbpath BBPATH] [-d] [-q]
               [--color COLOR] [-h]
               <subcommand> ...

OpenEmbedded development tool

optional arguments:
  --basepath BASEPATH  Base directory of SDK / build directory
  --bbpath BBPATH      Explicitly specify the BBPATH, rather than getting it
                       from the metadata
  -d, --debug          Enable debug output
  -q, --quiet          Print only errors
  --color COLOR        Colorize output (where COLOR is auto, always, never)
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit

subcommands:
  Beginning work on a recipe:
    add                  Add a new recipe
    modify               Modify the source for an existing recipe
    upgrade              Upgrade an existing recipe
  Getting information:
    status               Show workspace status
    search               Search available recipes
  Working on a recipe in the workspace:
    build                Build a recipe
    edit-recipe          Edit a recipe file in your workspace
    configure-help       Get help on configure script options
    update-recipe        Apply changes from external source tree to recipe
    reset                Remove a recipe from your workspace
  Testing changes on target:
    deploy-target        Deploy recipe output files to live target machine
    undeploy-target      Undeploy recipe output files in live target machine
    build-image          Build image including workspace recipe packages
  Advanced:
    create-workspace     Set up workspace in an alternative location
    extract              Extract the source for an existing recipe
    sync                 Synchronize the source tree for an existing recipe
Use devtool <subcommand> --help to get help on a specific command
```

Comment: I'm not at work, I can't check right now, but I'm pretty sure it still exists. Maybe you need to use `devtool create-workspace` first.

Comment: @Nayfe if followed exactly what Tim mentions in the video by creating a workspace using `create-workspace`. I have added the `devtool` help from the host machine and no such mention of `finish`.

Comment: Yocto Krogoth is quite old, maybe try to migrate to Rocko first.

Comment: @Nayfe you are right. The board I am using actually uses `krogoth` for all possible development. perhaps I will contact them for clarifications on `rocko`

Comment: Just checked the `2.1.2` Manual. Instead of `finish` one should use `reset` for older versions like `krogoth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Krogoth

for `krogoth` according to the [Yocto 2.1.2 Development Manual `devtool` manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1.2/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-devtool-in-your-workflow)

The created recipes need to be manually placed into the custom `meta-foo` layer.

For other versions `devtool finish recipe-name ../meta-foo` should do it for you.